# How do I ( or can I) add CSS style to an img in HTML.

Tags: html, css, web

The book I am using tells me to do the following:

img[title.jpeg] {border: 3px solid;}

This does not work, I have tried without the [title.jpeg] and it still does not work. How do identify an img element in a CSS style sheet? Does it matter that it is embedded in a H1 element?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the parent element before the img in your css to identify the correct image.

It does not matter if your image is in a `h1` tag as you can see in the example below.

You can also give the image a particular id to select only that image instead of trying with the image name.

```css
h1 img{
  width:50px;
}
#thisOne{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<h1><img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"/></h1>

<img id="thisOne" src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **inline CSS** within HTML with a *style* tag like this:

```
<img title="#" style="border: 3px solid" src="example.jpg"/>
```

Or, you can use **CSS**...
for example, you can add style to the *img* tag:

```
img {
border: 3px solid;
}
```

If you want to use CSS you can include a separate .css file or add the css code to your html file with `<style>` tags inside the `<head>` part of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The example from the book would only work if your file was named "title.jpeg" - and if they added:

img[src*="title.jpeg"]{ border: 3px; }

You could add a class, id or other identifier to your image and modify the class. Or you could use the above syntax and just make it match your file name.